# Facebook.login window doesn't appear

Tags: flash, facebook, authentication, window

I have a really strange problem with calling window facebook login from Flash.
On my private server facebook api works like a charm, but in my company, where we use very advanced application in flash and windows server the facebook login doesn't work..

I setup the HTML file correctly, I initialized Facebook.init(.. ..) and I call Facebook.login(.. ..) after clicking a button, but nothing happens, totally nothing, zero reaction.. Is there any way to debug this? Because Flash right now doesn't give me any errors...

Please help!

---

I have checked the connections, and
this is my http://labs.grzegorztomasiak.pl/facebook/ and it is connecting very well and I can see in debugging proxy that there are connections in facebook. BUT, at my work in 
http://demo.pptest.nl/chris-maris/Webstore.aspx#/home nothing happens, no responses, and connection in flash is the same like in my labs....

Answer (score 0):

It may be a Facebook application error. Check your application settings to confirm they are correct. If you're using OAuth2, then make sure your app settings are set to look for it. You should be able to use a web debugging proxy like Charles to view responses.